# How can I output Chinese characters in a specific font (of choice), not just any font

Tags: fonts, characters

How can I output Chinese characters in a specific font (i.e. a font of one's choice ... for example a .ttf file installed on your computer), not just any font? And does this require anything else than would be required for let's say the Roman alphabet?

Comment: If you use xetex or luatex then you can use any system installed truetype or opentype font, if you use pdftex then it is a lot of work to arrange a suitable collection of fonts and the required mappings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. That explains everything. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use xetex or luatex then you can use any system installed TrueType or OpenType font, if you use pdftex then it is a lot of work to arrange a suitable collection of fonts and the required mappings.