# Regular expressions ... how to also return the sequence splitting characters?

Tags: expl3, automation, l3regex

So, we have [this great regex code by User Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394174/67761) as an answer to my OP "[Automatically put certain inputs (e.g. punctuation marks) outside of the environment/command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394011/automatically-put-certain-inputs-e-g-punctuation-marks-outside-of-the-environ/394174?noredirect=1#comment979878_394174)":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_word_seq % define a new seqence
\NewDocumentCommand\IterateOverPunctutation{ m m }{
  % apply "function" #2 to the "words" in #1 between the punctuation characters
  \regex_split:nnN { [\.\,\;\:\s]+ } { #1 } \l_word_seq% split the sequence
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_word_seq {#2}% apply #2 to each word in \l_word_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Any[1]{``\textbf{#1}''\space}% a dummy \Any command

\IterateOverPunctutation{A, B: C. D}\Any

\end{document}
```

Which neatly produces:

[image]

And so it goes from:

`A, B: C. D`

to

`“`**`A`**`” “`**`B`**`” “`**`C`**`” “`**`D`**`”`

But my follow-up question now is ... how to go from (this is just an example ... see Andrew's code or linked OP for more info):

`A, B: C. D`

to e.g.

`“`**`A`**`”, “`**`B`**`”: “`**`C`**`”. “`**`D`**`”`

That is, how to still *also* output/repeat the separators (in this case `,` and `.` and `.` respectively)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listofitems` package can parse the input, either using nested levels of parsing, or (as is done here) with multiple (co-equal) parsing separators.  The macro `\setsepchar{.||,||:}` sets the coequal parsing characters `.`, `,`, and `:`.  No final separator (i.e., after the "D") is assumed, but can be changed if I misinterpreted the conditions.

While (in my MWE) `\mylist[<i>]` gives the i'th data field, `\mylistsep[<i>]` gives the separator following the i'th data field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\punctiterate[1]{%
  \setsepchar{.||,||:}%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{\ifnum\icnt>1\relax\mylistsep[\the\numexpr\icnt-1] \fi``\i''}
}
\begin{document}
\punctiterate{A, B: C. D}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

The OP would like to have `\par`s embedded in the input.  To achieve this goal, I use a 2-level parsing, with `\par` as the 2nd-level parsing separator.  If a `\par` is present in any 1st-level item, then the 2nd-level list length is 2, otherwise it is 1.  I can use this fact to intercept the presence of a `\par` and act accordingly.

[**UPDATE**:  Christian has updated the `listofitems` package to V1.4, available at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/listofitems. With the update, `\par` is once again available for use as a list separator.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\punctiterate[1]{%
  \setsepchar{.||,||:/\par}%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{%
    \ifnum\listlen\mylist[\icnt]>1\relax\par``\mylist[\icnt,2]''\else%
      ``\i''\fi\ifnum\icnt<\mylistlen\relax\mylistsep[\icnt] \fi%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\punctiterate{A, B: C. \par D}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow the code jams if there is a `\par` e.g in `\punctiterate{A, B: C. \par D}`... Do you see any solution there please?

Comment: Another question: your answer shows it is possible to surround each item with curly quotes ... but is it also possible to insert other commands around each item? For example `\textbf{`...`}`?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen How am I to interpret the `\par`?  Like a letter, like punctuation, or like something else.  That is to say, what do you expect the output to look like if there is a `\par` in the input?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Using `\textbf` is no problem...just change `\`\`\i''` to `\textbf{\i}`

Comment: I mean the regular definition and use of Tex's `\par`, to close a paragraph. You are right in that `\textbf ` is not a problem, my apologies ... I am having problems with another function`\tooltip{\i}`, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen I understand you mean the regular definition of `\par`, but I would like an explanation of how you want the output to look, when `\par` is in the input.

Comment: I guess to make the output look just as you would expect from a `\par`. :) To keep Tex able from interpreting it as a `\par` and outputting as such. So nothing different from what it would mean outside your code.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Please see my addendum.

Comment: Thank you. Please inform us once the **listofitems**-package has been updated to v1.4.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen The `listofitems` package has been updated and is available at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/listofitems.

Answer (score 2):

You want to grab the separators in `\regex_split:nnN`.  This is precisely what groups are for: just add parentheses to your pattern and whatever these parentheses match will show up in the resulting sequence.  Then when mapping through the sequence we need to keep track of odd versus even items because they will be words and separators respectively.  You may want to apply further regex processing on the separators to distinguish spaces and punctuation, and so on.  It may be useful to use a regex with more than one group (pair of parentheses) to separately grab the two, something like `([\.\,\;\:])([\s\c{par}]+)`.  Then the loop through the sequence would have to test `\int_mod:nn { \l_word_int } { 3 }` of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_word_seq % define a new sequence
\int_new:N \l_word_int % counts words to distinguish words and separators
\NewDocumentCommand\IterateOverPunctutation{ m m m }{
  % apply "function" #2 to the "words" in #1 between the punctuation characters
  \regex_split:nnN { ([\.\,\;\:\s]+) } { #1 } \l_word_seq% split the sequence
  \int_zero:N \l_word_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_word_seq
    {
      \int_incr:N \l_word_int
      \int_if_odd:nTF { \l_word_int }
        { #2 {##1} } % apply #2 to each word in \l_word_seq
        { #3 {##1} } % apply #3 to each separator in \l_word_seq
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Any[1]{``\textbf{#1}''}% a dummy \Any command
\newcommand\Thing[1]{\underline{#1}}% a dummy \Thing command

\IterateOverPunctutation{A, B: C. D}\Any\Thing

\end{document}
```

I didn't use `\seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn` because it has only been added 1 year ago and not everyone may have it.  With it you can avoid needing the `int` variable.