# Regular expression weirdness

Tags: expl3, l3regex

In answering [Automatically put certain inputs (e.g. punctuation marks) outside of the environment/command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394011) I wrote something very similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\Any[1]{``\textbf{#1}''\space}% a dummy command
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_word_seq % define a new sequence
\NewDocumentCommand\IterateOverPunctutation{ m }{
  % apply "function" #2 to the "words" in #1 between the punctuation  characters
    \regex_split:nnN { ([\(\)\.,;\:\s]+) } { #1 } \l_word_seq% split the sequence
    \cs_set:Nn \l_map_two:n {
       \regex_match:nnTF{ [\(\)\.,;\:\s]+ }{##1}
            {##1}% matches a punctuation character
            {\Any{##1}}% apply \Any to ##1
    }
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_word_seq \l_map_two:n
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\IterateOverPunctutation{A, (B: C. D)}

\IterateOverPunctutation{A), E,  G  H(;;,) (B: C. D)}

\IterateOverPunctutation{abc,a:b::def:f}

\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

*Can anyone explain to me the empty double quotes appear at the end of the first two lines?*

What is happening is that an empty string is being passed through to

```
\regex_match:nnTF{ [\(\)\.,;\:\s]+ }{##1}{##1}{\Any{##1}}
```

As the empty string does not match the regular expression it is then printed as `\Any{}`. My question really is why is `\regex_match:nnTF` putting an empty string into the sequence `\l_word_seq`?

If we change the match to

```
\regex_match:nnTF{ ^[\(\)\.,;\:\s]*$ }{##1}{##1}{\Any{##1}}
```

then we get the output that I expected:

[image]

because the new regular matches the "punctuation", the empty string and none of the "words". So it solves the problem but I still don't understand why the empty string can appear in the sequence returned by `\regex_split:nnN`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an empty item at the end of the sequence, if the token list ends with punctuation. You can remove it by checking whether the last item is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\Any[1]{``\textbf{#1}''\space}% a dummy command

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_word_seq % define a new sequence

\NewDocumentCommand\IterateOverPunctuation{ m }
 {
  % apply "function" #2 to the "words" in #1 between the punctuation  characters
    \regex_split:nnN { ([().,;:\s]{1,}) } { #1 } \l_word_seq% split the sequence
    \tl_if_empty:xT { \seq_item:Nn \l_word_seq { -1 } }
      { \seq_pop_right:NN \l_word_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
    \seq_map_function:NN \l_word_seq \__map_two:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nT { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__map_two:n
 {
   \regex_match:nnTF{ [().,;:\s] }{#1}
     {#1}% matches a punctuation character
     {\Any{#1}}% apply \Any to #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IterateOverPunctuation{AA, (B: C. D)}

\IterateOverPunctuation{A), E,  G  H(;;,) (B: C. D)}

\IterateOverPunctuation{abc,a:b::def:f}

\end{document}
```

I made a few changes, in particular you don't need to redefine `\__word_map:n` at each call (and it should be `protected`).

[image]

Comment: This is really a more precise description of *what* is happening rather than *why* it is happening. As far as I can see the manual does not mention this special feature of `\regex_split:nnN` adding an empty item when there is terminal punctuation and this is not a common feature of regular expressions in other languages. Is it intentional? Is it a bug? (Thanks for telling me about `\tl_if_empty:xT`, although my use of `\regex_match:nnTF` to deal with the issue seems more efficient in this instance.)

Comment: Ah, I take it back, it does happen in other languages! OK, I'll accept this then. This said, both latex and python, at least, are inconsistent because *initial* punctuation should lead to an empty item at the *start* of the sequence but neither of them do this.

Comment: @Andrew I don't know about Python, but consistency is the last thing I expect from Perl. `;-)`